# java.util.zip.ZipException when building react native app for android

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am trying to build a react native app for Android, unfortunately, it has been unsuccessful as I keep getting a java.util.zip.ZipException. I would really need a guide on how to fix this. I have node, java, python and android studio on my PC already, They all work fine, but still unable to build the react native app. This is an error log I get.

```
info Starting JS server...
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug)...

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
error: error reading C:\Users\Joshua Uyi\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading C:\Users\Joshua Uyi\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar; error in opening zip file

> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
java.util.zip.ZipException


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 15s
18 actionable tasks: 18 executed
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Comment: Have you tried the options mentioned in the error log under `* Try:`?

Comment: No, because the command runs only after I call react-native run-android and I cannot add an option to it. This "react-native run-android --stacktrace" doesn't work either